# Persist selected items in Telerik RadGrid (paging, sorting, filtering)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik-grid

I am working with the Telerik RadGrid and am needing to persist the selected items though paging, sorting & filtering. I found [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-persist-selected-rows-client-sorting-paging-grouping-filtering.html) example and have tried their example and get mixed results. At times it works in Chrome, albeit very buggy (sometimes only allows a single selection at a time). When I run it in IE I get this error

> unable to get value of the property 'get_element' object is null or
>   undefined

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var selected = {};
            function RadGrid_RowSelected(sender, args) {
                var rfp = args.getDataKeyValue("RFPID");
                if (!selected[rfp]) {
                    selected[rfp] = true;
                }
            }
            function RadGrid_RowDeselected(sender, args) {
                var rfp = args.getDataKeyValue("RFPID");
                if (selected[rfp]) {
                    selected[rfp] = null;
                }
            }
            function RadGrid_RowCreated(sender, args) {
                var rfp = args.getDataKeyValue("RFPID");
                if (selected[rfp]) {
                    args.get_gridDataItem().set_selected(true);
                }
            }
            function RadGrid_GridCreated(sender, eventArgs) {
                var masterTable = sender.get_masterTableView();
                var selectColumn = masterTable.getColumnByUniqueName("SelectColumnID");
                var headerCheckBox = $(selectColumn.get_element()).find("[type=checkbox]")[0];

                if (headerCheckBox) {
                    headerCheckBox.checked = masterTable.get_selectedItems().length ==
                        masterTable.get_dataItems().length;
                }
            }
    </script>
</telerik:RadScriptBlock>
```

And the grid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True"
                    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1NeedDataSource" Width="100%" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="false">
                    <MasterTableView AllowMultiColumnSorting="true" PageSize="100" 
                        DataKeyNames="RFPID, PropCode, Parent, PropName, Address" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="true" ClientDataKeyNames="RFPID">
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn />
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true"  />
                    </MasterTableView>    
                    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
                        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="True"></Scrolling>
                       <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                        <ClientEvents OnRowCreated="RadGrid_RowCreated" OnRowSelected="RadGrid_RowSelected"
                            OnRowDeselected="RadGrid_RowDeselected" OnGridCreated="RadGrid_GridCreated" />
                    </ClientSettings>  
                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

The IE error happens on this line:

> var headerCheckBox =
>   $(selectColumn.get_element()).find("[type=checkbox]")[0];

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Jquery includes.

```
 <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager2" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
```